# how to use "r --eval" in bash?

Tags: r, git, bash

I want to run the R code [from here](https://andrew.kvalhe.im/easy-calendar-heatmaps-for-git/) for bash:

```
git log --format=format:%cd --date=short --shortstat --no-merges master \
  | paste - - - | sort --key 1 | sed '$a\\' \
  | awk --field-separator "\t" '
    $1 != date { print date, ins, del; date = $1; ins = 0; del = 0; }
               { match($2, /([0-9]+) ins/, m); ins += m[1];
                 match($2, /([0-9]+) del/, m); del += m[1]; }' \
  | R --eval '
    library("makeR")
    attach(read.table(textConnection(readLines("stdin"))))
    png("heatmap.png")
    calendarHeat(V1, sapply(pmax(V2, V3), log))'
```

But there is no `r --eval` command at my bash, it says:

> WARNING: unknown option '--eval'

How should I run this?

Comment: You can use `R -e`. Or you install `littler` and use `r --eval`. But it seems that `r` uses a different startup process. At least in my case, it did not find my local library and could not load packages. So you are probably better off using `R -e`.

Comment: @Stibu:  Depends on a) what version of littler and b) where you set non-standard libpaths.  "Works for me." (TM)

Comment: `R -e ...` and `r -e ...` are two different things on all sane operating systems. Cupertino, of course, knows better ... or so they think.

Answer (score 1):

This definitely works.  Here is a quick ad-hoc shell script I made of your snippet:

```
#!/bin/sh

git log --format=format:%cd --date=short --shortstat --no-merges master | \
  paste - - - | sort --key 1 | sed '$a\\' | \
  awk --field-separator "\t" \
    '$1 != date { print date, ins, del; date = $1; ins = 0; del = 0; }
                { match($2, /([0-9]+) ins/, m); ins += m[1]; 
                  match($2, /([0-9]+) del/, m); del += m[1]; }' | \
  r -lmakeR -e'X <- read.table(textConnection(readLines("stdin"))); \
              png("heatmap.png"); \
              calendarHeat(X$V1, sapply(pmax(X$V2, X$V3), log)); \
              dev.off()'
```

which, when running in the repo our [Rblpapi](https://github.com/Rblp/Rblpapi) project, produces the image below.

[image]

I do use two [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) features here: `-l` to load a package (here [makeR](https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/makeR/) which I had to install from its archive, and `-e ...` for an expression. In `R` we would just prepend `library(makeR)` to the expression string...

Comment: Hm.., it gives me `WARNING: unknown option '-lmakeR'` and `WARNING: unknown option '-eX'`. But I have installed before both `makeR` and `littler`..

Comment: So you are on OS X which confuses `r` and `R`.  Poor you -- just make the last command `R -e 'library(makeR); X <- read.table(....as above....'`.

Comment: Now I succeed, thank you! But the output `*.png` is so low quality.. Don't you know how it may be fixed?

Comment: Use `help(png)` -- eg `png("heatmap.png", 800, 600)` would use that resolution.  These are _minor quibbles_ you can now work out at your end as we showed you a) how to get your data in and b) confirmed how to process it.

Comment: I am also interested in colors. With help of `help(calendarHeat)` I found only three available themes: `r2b` (red to blue), `r2g` (red to green), `w2b` (white to blue). But in [linked post](https://andrew.kvalhe.im/easy-calendar-heatmaps-for-git/) some nicier colors used. How to get them?

Comment: That has nothing to do with the initial question, and I suggest you pose a new, simplified, self-contained one with sample data.